# Comparar valores de um array multidmensional em php

Tags: php, array, comparação

Tenho o seguinte array preciso gerar confrontos entre eles aletorios sendo que os times dos mesmo array **Ex. Santos e São Paulo** não podem se enfrentar!!

```
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Santos"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "São Paulo"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Flamengo"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Gremio"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "Cruzeiro"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Sport"
  }
}
```

Meu resultado final será algo do tipo:

**Flamengo** x **Santos**
**São Paulo* x *Gremio**
**Sport** x **Cruzeiro**

Nunca **Santos x São Paulo**

Não consegui pensar uma forma de comparar os valores do array de forma dinamica visto que posso ter mais times inscritos!!

Comment: Seu exemplo ficou confuso. Poste o que possui e como deseja, para que fique mais claro.

Comment: Então eu tentei usar foreach para ver se os times estão no mesmo array, mais não consegui!!
Eu preciso criar um confronto entre ele sendo que os times que estão no mesmo array **ex. São Paulo e Santos** não poderam se enfrentar. Não sei se existe uma função que já pecorrar o array e faça essa comparação!!

Comment: Entendo, já tentei varias formas e não deu certo!! mas vou copiar aqui o código das tentativas. 

Enquanto isso o resultado final teria que ser algo do tipo:
*Sport x Cruzeiro*
*Gremio x São Paulo*
*Santos x Flamengo*

Sendo que esse confrontos devem ser aleatorios sendo que *São Paulo e Santos* não podem se enfrentar!!

Comment: Vai ser todos conta todos? tirando os que estão no mesmo array, seria isso. Você pode usar `in_array` para comparar se o time sorteado está no mesmo array ou se já foi gerando um jogo para ele.

Comment: Melhorou com a edição, mas ainda não dá pra entender esse array seu. Pq tem 2 itens no primeiro, e o resto é tudo time separado? Seria legal explicar melhor. Note que por mais que a comunidade tenha vontade de te ajudar, sem saber mais detalhes é inviável. Você sabe o que está tentando fazer, mas nós aqui só saberemos o que estiver na pergunta pra ser lido.

Comment: Entendi, o primeiro tem dois itens por ser times do mesmo estado então eles não podem se enfrentar na primeira rodada!!